# I'm getting an VariableDeclaratorID expected exception on my outputStream declaration

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileStreaming {

     private static FileWriter outputStream = null;

     private static File file = new File("Highscores.txt");
     private static outputStream = new FileWriter(file);
     private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how why it is throwing a  "Syntax error on token "outputStream", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" exception? This is for a java final and me and my group can't seem to find the error with this.

Comment: is that the full code?

Comment: @emaillenin no that is just the snippet of where the error is occurring.

Comment: Should there be a variable type for outputStream?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to re-declare `outputStream`.